# Directly reading files from AWS S3 without downloading json files in Golang

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, go, glide-golang

I am trying to develop a web application that parses JSON file AWS S3, Finally, save my local database. I don't save JSON files on my local machine. I want to read the JSON files directly from S3. Now I'm struggling to read JSON files, I cant read that parse JSON file. My workflow is `1.First read JSON file from amazon S3 withdout saving JSON file reading local machine 2.save on my DB`

```
func (s *Server) awsDataDownload(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    AWSRegion := "eu-west-2"
    AccessKeyID := "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    SecretAccessKey := "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    AWSBucketName := "sample-prod"

    _, err := envcfg.New()
    if err != nil {
        s.logger.WithError(err).Infof("Failed to initalize  AWS configuration")
        http.Error(res, "Failed to initalize  AWS configuration", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    userS3, err := s3.NewS3(s3.Config{
        Region:          AWSRegion,
        AccessKeyID:     AccessKeyID,
        SecretAccessKey: SecretAccessKey,
        Buckets: map[string]string{
            "userS3": AWSBucketName,
        },
    })

    if err != nil {
        s.logger.WithError(err).Infof("Failed to connect with  AWS")
        http.Error(res, "Failed to connect with  AWS", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    files, err := userS3.GetAllFiles(req.Context(), "userS3", "")

    if err != nil {
        s.logger.WithError(err).Infof("cannot load files from AWS")
        http.Error(res, "Failed to download with  AWS", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    for _, f := range files {
        awsUploadFile := AWSUploadedFile{
            FileName: f.FileName,
            URL:      f.URL,
            Created:  time.Time{},
            Size:     f.Size,
        }
        // json file match
        awsURLmatchJson := regexp.MustCompile(`.+?(.json)`).FindStringSubmatch(awsUploadFile.URL)[0]

        //companiesNameMatch := regexp.MustCompile(`.+?(.companies)`).FindStringSubmatch(awsUploadFile.URL)
        // date match
        awsURLmatchDateJson := regexp.MustCompile(`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`).FindStringSubmatch(awsUploadFile.URL)[0]
        //s.logger.Infof("%+v", awsURLmatchJson)
        //s.logger.Infof("%+v", awsURLmatchDateJson)

        if awsURLmatchDateJson == "2021-09-30" {
            s.fctDataDownload(res,req,awsURLmatchJson,awsUploadFile.URL, awsUploadFile.FileName)
        }
    }

    //s.logger.Info(":::::::::::::::::::::::AWS::::::::::::::::::::::::::::")
    //s.logger.Info(files)
    //s.logger.Infof("%+v", files)
}
```

Now, I got all files name, URL from this. Now I want to read JSON from getting this JSON file. this is my code

```
func (s *Server) fctDataDownload(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, awsURLmatchJson, URL, FileName string) {
    s.fctOrgProfile(res, req, awsURLmatchJson, URL, FileName)
    // s.fctOrgPeople(res, req)
    // s.fctOrgFundings(res, req)
}

    func (s *Server) fctOrgProfile(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, awsURLmatchJson, URL, FileName string) {
        s.logger.Infof("awsURLmatchJson %+v", awsURLmatchJson)
        //orgProfile := "/home/asad/go/src/codemen.org/json-dump-data/companies/companies.json"
        companiesNameMatch := regexp.MustCompile(`.+?(.people)`).FindStringSubmatch(awsURLmatchJson)
        s.logger.Infof("%+v", companiesNameMatch)
        if len(companiesNameMatch) < 1 {
            return
        }
        s.logger.Errorf(" companiesNameMatch %+v", companiesNameMatch)
        s.logger.Errorf(" FileName %+v", FileName)
        //orgProfile := companiesNameMatch
        jsonFile, err := os.Open(FileName)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("failed to open json file: %s, error: %v", FileName, err)
            s.logger.Errorf("%+v", companiesNameMatch)
            return
        }
//Rest code
```

But I'm getting this error

```
ERRO[0005]  FileName part-00000-c6c78231-f8ca-498c-b949-472b53074a57-c000.json 
failed to open json file: part-00000-c6c78231-f8ca-498c-b949-472b53074a57-c000.json, error: open part-00000-c6c78231-f8ca-498c-b949-472b53074a57-c000.json: no such file or directoryERRO[0005] [https://fct-apix-data-dump-prod.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/date%3D2021-09-30/people /people]
```

Comment: I think the error message is quite descriptive.

Comment: Yes, may be. It is cant open that file. How can I parse json file from directly?

Comment: Other AWS SDKS offer a way to read the object as a byte[]. Doesn't the GO SDK offer this functionality

Comment: Which SDK? Can you give me some reference

Comment: Please be sure to rotate your aws credentials immediately.

Comment: Yes, I rotate this

Answer (score 0):

JSON file is stored in S3, you can't read it with os.Open

```
jsonFile, err := os.Open(FileName)
```

replace it with `s3.GetObject`